# Is it safe to delete all .pyc files from the django root directory?

Tags: python

Is it safe to delete all .pyc files from the Django root directory? I ran the command below in my Django root directory:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec git rm -f "{}" \;
```

to delete .pyc files that I saw in my git check-in but the process went for quite some time and deleted hundred of .pyc files within every directory. I am a beginner in Python, Git and I am a bit concerned if this will have an impact on my Django code?

Comment: Yes, `.pyc` is Python bytecode. These are products of compilation, but will be recreated in case these do not exist.

Comment: yes, this shouldn't be a problem but instead of deleting this files you should use your `.gitignore`